# "What number am I thinking of" guessing game in Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

Here's my problem:

- I need to create a program in Scheme to play the "What number am I thinking of" game
- The parameters are the lower limit and the upper limit
- Every time a guess is taken, it is compared to the answer

  - if the guess is less, the it should say-go higher
  - if it's more, it should say -go lower
  - if it's equal, the print out "Winnner!".

Here is my current code:

```
(define (game low high)
   (let ((guess (average low high)))
       (cond ((islow? guess) (game (+ guess 1) high))
             ((ishigh? guess) (game low (- guess 1)))
              (else '(Winner!)))))
```

How do I implement `islow` and `ishigh`?

Comment: What else might `islow?/ishigh?` need to know?

Comment: Please don't post textbook questions.

Comment: (BTW, this question is part of [HtDP](http://htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-8.html#node_sec_5.1).)

Comment: islow and ishigh needs to compare the input guess with the stored correct answer. the the guess is higher, then we have to use a lower number and vice versa.

Comment: yea, I know that, but I do not have access to the solution to reference myself. I would appreciate an answer if you have one. @EliBarzilay

Comment: Yeah, I'm not thrilled by this question either.

Comment: I think Eli's HtDP reference was not primarily intended to help you search for the solution online :).

Comment: Yes, it was intended to explain why there is no answer, and to discourage people from answering it for you.

Comment: What is the problem with this question? Yes it's homework, but there's a sane description of the problem and a code sample, so what gives?

Comment: @Kev, the reason that Eli and John (and I) are unhappy is that posting answers to textbook questions makes life harder for all users of the textbook.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like a binary-search.

```
while (true){
    response = guess(number);
    if(response == true) return "Found it!";
    if(response == 'higher'){
        number = number+maximum/2;
    }
    else if(response == 'lower'){
        number = number+minimum/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Then do it ^^ We're not here to do your homework, and trust me, we've all been through this sometime in our lives.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misinterpreting your assignment – if so, let me know.

Your function doesn't actually know what the correct answer is! This might be why you're confused about `islow?` and `ishigh?`...

So I think the first thing your function needs to do is come up with the correct answer, which will be a number between `low` and `high`. You can do this with the `(random k)` function, which picks a random number between 0 and `k-1`. The first problem is to figure out how to use that to get a number between `low` and `high`.

Once you have the `answer`, then `islow?` and `ishigh?` are straightforward, and I don't think you need to make separate functions for them; just use `>` and `<`.

You also need to let the user input a guess repeatedly, right? It might be easiest if for now, you just say that you're going to make a function `get-guess` that'll ask the user for input, and then figure that out later.

Comment: The program does need an input and it should be of this following type:
> (guess 5)
What number am I thinking?
4
higher.
6
lower.
5
Yes, you win.